Credentials for Turn Server in WebRtc
I have been trying to connect to a Turn server for WebRtc in my application I have been told that the server only has a password and not a username.
when I do have a username and a password I use the below configuration and it works fine.
but how should I connect to a turn server which only have a password/credential?
'iceServers': [
      {
        'username': 'username',
        'credential': 'password',
        'urls': [
          'stun:stun.*****.com',
          'turn:turn.*****.com'
        ]
      }
    ]


You may try the following:
iceServers': [
  {
    'username': 'username',
    'credential': 'password',
    'urls': [
           'turn:turn.*****.com'
    ]
  },
  {
    'username': 'username',
    'credential': 'password',
    'urls':'turn:turn.*****.com'
  },
]

